# What should I do with a large gap in a concrete floor

Tags: concrete

The grout in the tile has cracked or separated all the way across the house from one side to the other. I figured it was normal due to settling. In the kitchen it has become really bad, to the point the tiles are cracking and there is approximately a 1/4in difference in height. I decided to replace the cracked tiles and discovered a large gap in the floor real close to 1/2in wide.

Should I worry about this or should I just replace the tiles and let it go. The house is 7 years old.

Comment: It sounds like your foundation is settling unevenly on on side vs the other. Are you in an area known for sinkholes, or straddling a fault line?  It's probably just a little settling of the foundation on one side of the house. No idea if you'd have any kind of claim against the builder or your insurance policy.

Comment: There are several things that could be a problem. Most likely it is foundation settling, but also could be faulty slab (no reinforcement in it, gravel under it isn't well compacted) or even underground water level has risen. Is the slab on the ground level, is it connected with foundations or walls or is it "floating" meaning that it is separated from other construction elements. Do you maybe know what type of foundation do you have?

Answer (score 1):

That is a major issues, especially on a new home. Call the developer. They have a right to repair it before you pursue legal options.